# check for value1 in col 1 and value 4 in col 4 and print whole line, bash

Tags: bash, awk, find

I have a `data.txt` file.

```
    1   2    3     4       5       6       7
    cat data.txt
1   10 100 1100 10.0000 10.1122 60.0000 60.1111 
2   11 110 1110 10.1122 10.3333 60.1111 61.3333
3   12 120 1120 10.3333 11.0547 61.3333 61.9999
4   13 130 1130 11.0547 11.1111 61.9999 62.4444
5   14 140 1140 11.1111 10.1122 62.4444 62.8888
6   15 150 1150 10.1122 10.3333 61.3333 61.9999 
7   16 160 1160 10.3333 11.1111 60.1111 61.3333
8   17 170 1170 11.0547 11.5555 61.3333 64.1111
9   18 180 1180 10.3333 11.1111 61.3333 61.3333
10  19 190 1190 11.0547 11.5555 60.1111 64.1111
11  20 200 1200 11.1111 10.1122 62.4444 62.8888
```

I wanted to find the find all the values sequentially from `10.1122` in `column 4` to `11.1111`. And the values sequentially from `60.1111` in `column 6` to `61.9999`.

'anubhava' and 'kent' suggested (Thanks!) to use

`awk -v col=4 -v start=10.1122 -v end=11.1111 '$col>=start && $col<=end{
              print $col}' data.txt | sort -nu`

```
   1  10.1122 
   2  10.3333
   3  11.0547
   4  11.1111
```

`awk -v col=6 -v start=60.1111 -v end=61.9999 '$col>=start && $col<=end{
              print $col}' data.txt | sort -nu`

```
   1  60.1111 
   2  61.3333
   3  61.9999
```

I want to print/save in a results.txt file the lines where in

```
col4: 10.1122 && col6: 60.1111
col4: 10.3333 && col6: 60.1111
col4: 11.0547 && col6: 60.1111
col4: 10.1122 && col6: 61.3333
col4: 10.3333 && col6: 61.3333
col4: 11.0547 && col6: 61.3333
```

means the lines -->

```
2   11 110 1110 10.1122 10.3333 60.1111 61.3333
6   15 150 1150 10.1122 10.3333 61.3333 61.9999 
7   16 160 1160 10.3333 11.1111 60.1111 61.3333
8   17 170 1170 11.0547 11.5555 61.3333 64.1111
9   18 180 1180 10.3333 11.1111 61.3333 61.3333
10  19 190 1190 11.0547 11.5555 60.1111 64.1111
```

Any suggestion? That is why I was expecting the awk results to be stored in array1 and array2 so that can find the lines where col4 value and col6 value exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too confusing. Please edit so it's more obvious.

Comment: why line #3 #4 ... not in result?

Comment: Because the `line #3` and `line #9` is same. It should print only one evidence of `col4: 10.3333 && col6: 61.3333`
`Line #4` has `col4: 11.0547 && col6: 61.9999`

I just want the pairs until second last values from both cols, 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line should do:

```
awk -v f4=10.1122 -v t4=11.1111 -v f6=60.1111 -v t6=61.9999 
      '$4>=f4&&$4<=t4&&$6>=f6&&$6<=t6' file
```

result is:

```
11 110 1110 10.1122 10.3333 60.1111 61.3333
12 120 1120 10.3333 11.0547 61.3333 61.9999
13 130 1130 11.0547 11.1111 61.9999 62.4444
15 150 1150 10.1122 10.3333 61.3333 61.9999 
16 160 1160 10.3333 11.1111 60.1111 61.3333
17 170 1170 11.0547 11.5555 61.3333 64.1111
18 180 1180 10.3333 11.1111 61.3333 61.3333
19 190 1190 11.0547 11.5555 60.1111 64.1111
```

note that, with the criteria defined by you: the line starting with `12 and 13` should be in output as well.

Also, the line numbers are added by you, but not in the file right? otherwise the column4 would be column5... so I just removed the first line number column.

Comment: Thanks Kent. It works! 
I edited the part `'$4>=f4&&$4<t4&&$6>=f6&&$6<t6'` as I do not want to cross match the last values from both col4&&col6. 
But the problem is that it also prints the lines where there are more than one instances of `col4:val4&&col6:val6`. Any suggestion to avoid this?